# How to implement map that returns always the same value?

Tags: scala

I have a following interface:
`def some(foo: Map[SomeObject, String])`

How to pass to this function argument such that it returns always the same thing? In other words map such that return always `"bar"` string ?

Comment: `def some(foo: Map[SomeObject, String]) = "bar"` ?

Comment: `Map.empty[SomeObject, String].withDefault("bar")` as I always say, the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html) is your friend.